# Calculate Delta Between Two Dates using Python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two datetime columns (dtype =  datetime64[ns]) in pandas. I can successfully calculate the delta in hours, but I want the result to be days.

Example

```
foo_df = pd.DataFrame({'date_1': ['2019-08-07 09:25:07'], 
                       'date_2': ['2019-08-08 01:01:00']}).astype('datetime64[ns]')

foo_df['delta'] =  foo_df['date_2'] - foo_df['date_1']
```

result

```
    date_1              date_2              delta
0   2019-08-07 09:25:07 2019-08-08 01:01:00 15:35:53
```

Desired Result

```
    date_1              date_2              delta
0   2019-08-07 09:25:07 2019-08-08 01:01:00 1
```

NOTE: The delta should be 1 because date_2 is the *next day*. I only need to calculate if the day is different. I can do this if I convert the date columns to strings, but ideally, I'd like to avoid that since this should be possible to do with dtype; datetime64[ns]

Comment: are you looking for `(foo_df['date_2'].dt.date - foo_df['date_1'].dt.date).dt.days` ?

Comment: dt.days() should work, since you are interested in that part of the datetime

Comment: Bingo! that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the dates, then get the [number of days](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#timedelta-properties) from the Timedelta:

`foo_df['delta'] = (foo_df.date_2.dt.date - foo_df.date_1.dt.date).dt.days`